# Sending JSON object to Spring controller

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc

Could someone please tell me why I am getting empty body in the controller. Here is my test

```
 public void updatePackage() throws Exception {

    JSONObject updateObj = new JSONObject();

    updateObj.append("packageType", "packageType-update-endpoint");


    SPackage updatedResponse = null;

    try {
        String json = updateObj.toString();
        System.out.println("**** JSON **** ");
        System.out.println(json + "----------" + this.response.getId());
        ResultActions result = mvcController.perform(put("/package/" + this.response.getId())
                .content(json)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk());
        updatedResponse = JsonUtil.<SPackage>convertJsonToObject(
                result.andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString(), SPackage.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail("Unexpected exception" + e);
    }

}
```

and here my controller method

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/package/{id}", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
@ResponseBody
public SPackage updatePackage(@PathVariable String id, @RequestBody JSONObject sPackage) {
    if (sPackage == null) {
        throw new BadRequestException("Given package is null");
    }

    return softwarePackageService.updatePackage(id,sPackage);
}
```

I am using Spring MVC Controller Mock

Comment: have tried using string and then convert it to the json object

Comment: if your method is this public void updatePackage() then why u using this for call updatePackage(id,sPackage)?

Comment: thanks...your first suggestion worked for me

Comment: I am happy that it worked for you :)

Comment: Do u get the reason why its not working if you give jsonobject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try to Give datatype only `String` and try to convert it to the `Json format` at the Server side.
and hope that will work.

So simple solution is Send `String` and convert into the `JSON`

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code as follows.

```
           ResultActions result = mvcController.perform(put("/package/" + this.response.getId())
            .content(new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(updateObj.toString()))
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andDo(print())
            .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

I need to do a .toString() to json object and then pass to the ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString method